# Speech to text in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

I was wandering if there is any free software that can turn speech to text and that can write in LibreOffice Writer. If there are other languages supported except english like Italian, Greek and Spanish that would be wonderfull.

Thank you in advance!